# Why does SD card from Nikon D90 ask for user name and password on Windows XP?

Tags: nikon-d90, sdhc

I have a SanDisk Extreme 32GB SDHC memory card from my Nikon D90 and when I plug it into my Windows XP machine it first asked for a username and password, and giving one, it now says 'Not accessible, The directory name is invalid.'  It shows as a drive named: canon_memory on '75822e000000'.

Please suggest how I can view my pictures on the computer.  I'm trying Nikon Transfer for usb connect, but would rather read the card directly if possible.

Comment: That's weird. You'll probably have better results on http://superuser.com/ .

Comment: To make my earlier comment stronger: this is a computer problem, not a camera problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ensure you have the current images copied off via Nikon Transfer with your D90 connected directly to your computer, then I would suggest using the D90 to format the entire memory card to remove any pre-installed software and/or directories.  This should resolve any access issues when putting the memory card in to a card reader.

On the D90 there are two buttons used to format the memory card, the Metering button and the Format button.  Hold them both down together until the LCD screen flashes 'FOR', then release and push them together again, this will format the card ready for use.

As a habit I do this every time I start a shoot, just to ensure that any bad sectors are not used and that any old files are not taking space.

Let us know how you get on.

Comment: Formatting the card did not help, issue remains, will post over at superuser.